# In C++ what does this construction mean "InterceptionKeyStroke &kstroke = * (InterceptionKeyStroke *) &stroke"?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a novice in C++ and don't understand this construction.

```
InterceptionKeyStroke &kstroke = * (InterceptionKeyStroke *) &stroke
```

I know that & = pointer. But what does this mean?

```
* (InterceptionKeyStroke *)
```

Comment: How much do you know about *casting*? How much do you know about pointers and *dereferencing* them?

Comment: ... I think your better consult our [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I am reading now "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++", but at the same time I need to rewrite some python script to c++ in no time.

Answer (score 10):

Breaking it down:

```
InterceptionKeyStroke     // a type...
&                         // ...which is by reference
kstroke                   // named 'kstroke'
=                         // bound to (since references are bound)
*                         // something that a pointer points to
(InterceptionKeyStroke*)  // "I know what the type is!" cast
&                         // address of...
stroke                    // ...variable named 'stroke'
```

So the `*(InterceptionKeyStroke*)` is casting to a pointer, and then dereferencing the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that & = pointer.

Your knowledge is incomplete. `&` has multiple meanings in C++. The `&` you refer to is the address-of operator, as in:

```
int i = 0;
int* ptr = &i; // `ptr` contains address of `i`
```

In `InterceptionKeyStroke &kstroke`, the `&` is used to declare a **reference**, and only the second `&`, i.e. the one in `* (InterceptionKeyStroke *) &stroke` is the address-of operator I mentioned above.

> But what does this mean?
>
> ```
> * (InterceptionKeyStroke *)
> ```

It's a C-style cast which means that a pointer should be interpreted as if it was an `InterceptionKeyStroke *`. The result of that operation is then dereferenced, via the dereference operator `*` at the left, to get an `InterceptionKeyStroke` object.

So the entire `InterceptionKeyStroke &kstroke = * (InterceptionKeyStroke *) &stroke` line is as if you told the compiler the following:

*"Let kstroke be a reference to InterceptionKeyStroke, and let that reference refer to the stroke object. And yes, I know that when I take the address of stroke, then I get a pointer that doesn't technically point to an InterceptionKeyStroke. So please just interpret it as if it pointed to an InterceptionKeyStroke, because I know that it does. Now that we've established it's an InterceptionKeyStroke pointer we are talking about, dereference that pointer to obtain the object for the reference to refer to."*

I should mention that this code looks very fishy. How comes `stroke` isn't already an `InterceptionKeyStroke` in the first place? What's the relationship between `InterceptionKeyStroke` and the type of `stroke`? I have a strong feeling that you've got undefined behaviour in your program, because the C-style cast subverts the compiler's error-detection mechanism. If you lie to the compiler, then anything can happen.